# Fill multiple input with bootstrap typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm new whit the typeahead plug in.

I would like to know if it is possible to fill 2 input with this plugin,
in detail i have one text field and an hidden field.

The data structure is `[{id: int, value: String, tokens: [...]}, ... ]`

When the user selects a suggestion I would like to fill the hidden field with the `id` of the datum and the visible field with the value

Which do you think is the best solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed possible. Very common since typeahead only treats simple array of strings. Use the `updater`-function, like this

**html**, typeahead and hidden field

```
<input type="text" id="typeahead" name="typeahead" placeholder="type some text" data-provide="typeahead">
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="hidden">
```

**script**

```
//test JSON (doesnt know what you mean by "datum" and what token is)
var json = [
    { 'id' : '1', 'value' : 'value1', 'tokens' : '' },
    { 'id' : '2', 'value' : 'value2', 'tokens' : '' },
    { 'id' : '3', 'value' : 'value3', 'tokens' : '' }
];

//create an array of values for the typeahead
var typeaheadArray = [];
for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
    typeaheadArray.push(json[i].value);
}

//the "magic" goes in the updater-function
// when you select an item from the list, updater looks up the 
// corresponding id and set the value of #hidden to that id 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#typeahead").typeahead({
        source: typeaheadArray,
        updater: function(item) {
            for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
                if (json[i].value==item) {
                    $("#hidden").val(json[i].id);
                    return;
                 }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: datum and tokens refer to the documentati on 
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#datum anyway

Comment: the function is never called!! 
and i'm not using a local array but i call a servlet that pass me the array so its a bit tricky to use your solution...

i was looking for a way to modify the standard handler handleSelection to do that work...

Comment: Of course, you have not provided any data, so I had to make a test-json. Expected you could manage to use the output from the servlet instead of json[]. If the updater is never called, I guess you never get any data. Give a real example of the data. There is no such "standard handler" as "handleSelection" - updater is that - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Answer (score 0):

(almost) OK !!
i have modified the handler like this..

```
_handleSelection: function(e) {
            var byClick = e.type === "suggestionSelected", suggestion = byClick ? e.data : this.dropdownView.getSuggestionUnderCursor();
            if (suggestion) {
                this.inputView.setInputValue(suggestion.value);
                this.inputView.setHiddenValue(suggestion.datum.id); // <-- here is the mod
                byClick ? this.inputView.focus() : e.data.preventDefault();
                byClick && utils.isMsie() ? utils.defer(this.dropdownView.close) : this.dropdownView.close();
                this.eventBus.trigger("selected", suggestion.datum);
            }
        }
```

where i added this.inputView.setHiddenValue(suggestion.datum.id);

I defined the method as follows

```
setHiddenValue: function(value) {
                id = this.$input.attr('id')+'-code';
                $('#'+id).val(value);
            }
```

and the markup...

```
<input class="span3" type="text" placeholder="Customer" id="customer" name="" value="" >
<input type="hidden" id="customer-code" name="customer" value="" >
```

maybe there is a cleaner solution, any feedback is welcome....